# how to generate the buttons using Button class?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
public void BindBatches()
{
    DataTable dtgetbatches = new DataTable();
    divBatches.Controls.Clear();
    dtgetbatches = breederdailybal.GetBreederBatches();
    if (dtgetbatches.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < dtgetbatches.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Button btnbatch = new Button();
            btnbatch.ID = dtgetbatches.Rows[i]["batch"].ToString();

            btnbatch.Width = 90;
            btnbatch.ForeColor = Color.White;
            btnbatch.BackColor = Color.Green;
            btnbatch.Click += new EventHandler(btnbatch_Click);

            divBatches.Controls.Add(btnbatch);
            LiteralControl @break1 = default(LiteralControl);
            @break1 = new LiteralControl("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp");
            divBatches.Controls.Add(@break1);
       }
    }
}
```

i want to show the buttons based on dtgetbatches object.
it doesn't generate the normal buttons what's the problem please help meout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public void BindBatches()
   {
    DataTable dtgetbatches = new DataTable();
    divBatches.Controls.Clear();
    dtgetbatches = breederdailybal.GetBreederBatches();
    if (dtgetbatches.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < dtgetbatches.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Button btnbatch = new Button();
            btnbatch.ID = dtgetbatches.Rows[i]["batch"].ToString();
            btnbatch.Text = "Batch" + " " + dtgetbatches.Rows[i]["batch"].ToString();
            btnbatch.Width = 90;
            btnbatch.ForeColor = Color.White;
            btnbatch.BackColor = Color.Green;
            btnbatch.Click += new EventHandler(btnbatch_Click);

            divBatches.Controls.Add(btnbatch);
            LiteralControl @break1 = default(LiteralControl);
            @break1 = new LiteralControl("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp");
            divBatches.Controls.Add(@break1);
       }
    }
```

}

you are not adding the btnbatch.text properity...how it's read the data based on dtgetbatches...so carely write and add this code